# Children Breaking Out of Parent DIV

Tags: css

I'm having trouble containing elements within their parent. And, honestly, I've lost myself within the code. If you visit the page here:

[Home Page](http://clients.realintegrated.com/cammenga/)

You'll see that first DIV underneath the header area. Inside of there, the words and product meta class are supposed to be contained within their part. Something is going on to where they're breaking out however, and I can't see my problem.

[Home Page Comp](https://invis.io/893R4W7HW)

HTML:

```
<div class="masonry-block masonry-0">
    <div class="masonry-0__skew">

        <div class="wrap">

            <div class="six-left">
                <p>AM I A SLIDER? I'M NOT SURE YET!</p>
            </div>

            <div class="six-right">
                <div class="product-meta bottom">
                    <div class="product-title">
                        PRODUCT TITLE HERE
                    </div>
                    <div class="shop-now btn">
                        SHOP NOW
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
  padding: 6.25rem 0;
  margin: -2rem 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%), url("http://placehold.it/350x150");
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 ), url("http://placehold.it/350x150");
  @include media-query(desk) {
    padding: 6.25rem 1rem;
  }
  @include media-query(lap-and-down) {
    padding: 6.25rem 1rem;
  }
}

// Home Page Craziness
.masonry-block {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: gutter();
}
.masonry-0 {
  @include span(12);
  @include height(600px);
  background: url("http://wallpoper.com/images/00/44/24/16/bullets-4_00442416.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.masonry-0__skew {
  &:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    transform: skewY(-1deg);
    border-top: 4px solid $green;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    @include media-query(lap-and-down) {
      transform: none;
    }
  }
}
.six-left {
  @include span(6);
  @include media-query(lap-and-down) {
    @include span(12);
  }
}
.six-right {
  @include span(6 last);
  @include media-query(lap-and-down) {
    @include span(12);
  }
}
.masonry-1 {
  @include span(4);
  @include height(400px);
  background: url("http://wallpoper.com/images/00/44/24/16/bullets-4_00442416.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  @include media-query(lap-and-down) {
    @include span(12);
  }
}
.masonry-2 {
  @include span(8 last);
  @include height(400px);
  background: url("http://wallpoper.com/images/00/44/24/16/bullets-4_00442416.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  @include media-query(lap-and-down) {
    @include span(12);
  }
}
.masonry-3 {
  @include span(12);
  @include height(400px);
  background: url("http://wallpoper.com/images/00/44/24/16/bullets-4_00442416.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  @include media-query(lap-and-down) {
    @include span(12);
  }
}
.product-meta {
  margin: 1rem;
}
.product-title {
  font-family: $main-font-fam;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: $white;
}
.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

UPDATE: I've found that the issue seems to be the floats applied to the Susy grids I'm using. So I had to add positioning to the inner wrap and then add a height to the containing element. Everything seems to be good now.

Comment: Post the related styles here as well

Comment: Please include enough code in the question to reproduce your issue, rather than linking to an external website. Also, you have only tagged this question with [tag:css], but your question has no CSS in it.

Comment: I'd consider adding a border of 20px so the children can't get out

Comment: A border? Or a margin/padding?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the issue seems to be the floats applied to the Susy grids I'm using. So I had to add positioning to the inner wrap and then add a height to the containing element. Everything seems to be good now.